# Telegram bot commands stopped responding abruptly, what’s wrong?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, polling, python-telegram-bot

I’ve been working on a telegram bot and I just managed to design it to handle commands and issue responses to users.

I was able to achieve this successfully and started testing each and every command repeatedly to ensure they work, mind you these are like 6 or 7 commands. Basically user sends the /command and my bot sends feedback and that for like the very first few tries, like it really worked then suddenly it all stopped working.

The welcome message for new group users from the bot the feature still works but the commands aren’t.

I didn’t register all commands with BotFather but they worked anyway regardless so I’m not sure that’s the problem.

Comment: take some time and read these articles first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ; https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please include some code in your question, otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: Which service are you using?